# Python to_excel not generating output file

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am trying to output a dataframe to an excel file. My code runs without any errors but there is no output file generated in the given directory (or elsewhere).

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\OneDrive\\Membership\\merged_part.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter', mode='w')
df_merged_part.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Merged part')
writer.save()
```

I have checked the working directory and the rest of my PC for the files. I have uninstalled and re-installed Spyder (anaconda) in case it was the fact my laptop has recently upgraded to Windows 11 and there were any issues. Other threads have suggested variations on `\` and `"` or `r'`; or using `writer.save`. No joy.

Comment: Are you sure that this code snippet is running? You could test it by putting a print statement after `writer.save()`

Comment: @iHowell good thinking, but, just tested it and it is definitely executing.

Comment: try to write in local folder instead of `OneDrive` server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my AntiVirus (Comodo) was running Anaconda applications in a sandbox and refusing to write outputs.